# ElasticSearch version 8 - how to pass custom http client?

Tags: go, http, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate

I have this:

```
    httpClient := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                InsecureSkipVerify: true, // Skip certificate verification
            },
        },
    }

    esClient, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(elasticsearch.Config{
        HTTPClient: httpClient,
        Addresses: []string{
            conf.GetConf().ES_FULL_URL,
        },
    })
```

but this doesn't work - I looked at the source code and config doesn't seem to accept a custom http client..

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/102780

Answer (score 0):

The API *changed* - this works:

```
httpClient := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true, // Skip certificate verification
        },
    },
}

esClient, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(elasticsearch.Config{
    Transport: httpClient.Transport,  // HERE
    Addresses: []string{
        conf.GetConf().ES_FULL_URL,
    },
})
```

strange unnecessary API change..it seems